# Cakephp 2.6 - form submition redirects to homepage instead of action

Tags: php, cakephp

when i submit a form i get redirected to home page instead of saving data.
i'm not using any custom routing.

this is how i create the form:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Presentation', array('type'=>'POST' ,'url'=>array('controller'=>'admin', 'action'=>'edit_presentation',$this->request->data['Presentation']['id'])));
```

and this is the action:

```
public function edit_presentation($id = null) {
    $this->uses = array('Presentation');
    $this->loadModel('Presentation');
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        // var_dump($this->request->data);
        // exit();
        $this->Presentation->locale = Configure::read('Config.languages');
        if ($this->Presentation->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The hotel has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'presentation'));
        }
    }
    $this->request->data = $this->Presentation->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Presentation.id'=>$id)));
    foreach ($this->request->data as $field => $trad) {
        if (strpos($field, '_')===0) {
            $name = str_replace('_', '', $field);
            $this->request->data['Presentation'][$name] = array();
            foreach ($trad as $value) {
                $locale = $value['locale'];
                $this->request->data['Presentation'][$name][$locale] = $value['content'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Presentation->id = $id;
$this->Presentation->locale = Configure::read('Config.languages');
if ($this->Presentation->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The hotel has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'presentation'));
}
```

try this out and give me feedback

Comment: Thank you for your response, the problem is that when i submit the form the action is not called at all, and this happens only in production server, in local server works as expected.

Comment: you what try this from your form creation 
`$id = $this->request->data['Presentation']['id'];
echo $this->Form->create('Presentation', array('type'=>'POST' ,'url'=>array('controller'=>'admin', 'action'=>'edit_presentation/' . $id)));`

Comment: if i may ask is it redirecting you back to **edit_presentation** page?

Comment: do you use exactly the same database version in Dev and Prod? maybe something with relations between the tables isn't configured the same on the 2 servers?

Comment: @SelaYair not really i don't use same database versions...
but codes works just fine both in Prod and Dev

Comment: Thank you all for your help, the problem now is solved i don't know how but i think it is something with the server, it is really strange because the next day when i checked the error it's simply gone.